# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. AAPT: error: resource string/app_name not found

Tags: android, dart, flutter

When I'm going to run App in the Android device I got below error message.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>     Android resource linking failed
>     /Users/uzerx/Documents/Ameerrraj/Work/ClubEvent/club_event/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:65: AAPT: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.mobileapp.club_event:string/app_name) not found.
>
>   error: failed processing manifest.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 25s
>   The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
>   See for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
>   Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Where I'm going wrong.

Below is **AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]

and **project/gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**EDITED**

> strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">2206883509627625</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb2206883509627625</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please check strings.xml have this `"@string/app_name"`. If not then please add.

Comment: <string name="app_name">Your App Name here.</string>
that's missing .. thnaks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<string name="app_name">Your App Name here</string>` is missing please add this.

Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App Name here</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">2206883509627625</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb2206883509627625</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a string resource name app_name

Go to android folder and look for the res/ directory. Under there you should find a strings.xml file. Look if there is something like

Your App Name should be here

If its not there then you should put it

Comment: can you please elaborate more